# How to assign content trust policy to container registry resource azure powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-deployment, azure-container-registry

I have created container registry as below through powershell.

```
$prop = @{
        Location          = "..."
        ResourceName      = "Resource1"
        ResourceType      = "Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries" 
        ResourceGroupName = "ResourceGroup.." 
        Force             = $true
        Sku               = @{"Name"="Premium"}
        }
       $registry = New-AzResource @prop"
```

It gets created successfully, but the content trust policy set for this is "disabled"
How can i make it enabled during creation through powershell

Comment: Could you try something similar to `az acr config content-trust update -r MyRegistry --status Enabled`

Comment: @Matthew This command runs through Azure Cli, I need some mechanism to do through powershell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content trust policy for the ACR is in its properties, so you need to set it in the commands. Finally, the commands will like this:

```
$prop = @{
    Location            ="location"
    ResourceName        ="resourceName"
    ResourceType        ="Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries"
    ResourceGroupName   ="groupName"
    Sku                 =@{"Name"="Premium"}
    Properties          =@{"Policies"=@{"TrustPolicy"=@{"Type"="Notary";"Status"="enabled"}}}
}
$registry = New-AzResource @prop
```

Comment: Thanks it worked - I added content trust policy in properties